# onEdit(e) script works halfway but when I change it to script run when I click it works - need it to work for mobile

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

Happy New Year - Thank you in advance for helping me with this!
I need to run my script on a mobile.  The script works perfectly on a desktop as I can just click it on a button but as I change it to an "onEdit(e)" script it works only part of the way.
Here is the source page where the script should run from on mobile - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wq8jI87A2PkRuwnDzl0fjV7bUSRPkc6JfRQNLvYBN_s/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the destination page where the script is sending data to -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CYZO6fP3APscxDLS881x3eJ9YEC9ydBXDxvmPaSUwU0/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the script -

```
function checkValue() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var s = ss.getSheetByName("SCAN");
 var valueToCheck = s.getRange("A5").getValue();
 
 
 if (valueToCheck == true){
      
    var theRoll = s.getRange("A4").getValue();
    var statusPage = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CYZO6fP3APscxDLS881x3eJ9YEC9ydBXDxvmPaSUwU0');
    var statusSheet = statusPage.getSheetByName("DailyCut");
    var lr1=statusSheet.getLastRow();
    var range = statusSheet.getRange(2,1,lr1-1,4).getValues();
    var barCode = s.getRange("A2").getValue();
     
      for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
             if(barCode==range[j][1]){
             statusSheet.getRange(j+2,16).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('h:mm');
             statusSheet.getRange(j+2,14).setValue("Robin");
             statusSheet.getRange(j+2,15).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-mm-yyyy');
             statusSheet.getRange(j+2,17).setValue(theRoll);
             j = range.length;
     
     }
      }
      
      s.getRange(2,1).setValue("");
      s.getRange(4,1).setValue("");
      s.getRange(5,1).setValue(false);
}
}
```

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Use [code fences](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your code. [Test formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) before posting questions.

Comment: You need to use installable edit trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a checkbox to trigger your function then this should work for you.  Just remember to rename your function to something other than onEdit and create an
installible trigger and add the e to collect the event object from the trigger

```
function newfunctionname(e) {
  const s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'SCAN' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");//set the check box back to false      
    var theRoll = s.getRange("A4").getValue();
    var statusPage = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CYZO6fP3APscxDLS881x3eJ9YEC9ydBXDxvmPaSUwU0');
    var statusSheet = statusPage.getSheetByName("DailyCut");
    var lr1 = statusSheet.getLastRow();
    var range = statusSheet.getRange(2, 1, lr1 - 1, 4).getValues();
    var barCode = s.getRange("A2").getValue();
    for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
      if (barCode == range[j][1]) {
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 16).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('h:mm');
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 14).setValue("Robin");
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 15).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-mm-yyyy');
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 17).setValue(theRoll);
        j = range.length;

      }
    }
    s.getRange(2, 1).setValue("");
    s.getRange(4, 1).setValue("");
    s.getRange(5, 1).setValue(false);
  }
}

function createinstallableonedittrigger() {
 if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == "newfunctionnname").length == 0) {
   ScriptApp.newTrigger('newfunctionname').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
 }
}
```

Comment: Could you guide me how to create an installable trigger. After posting, I did some research and found out onEdit cannot post data on other spreadsheets so you found a nice workaround but I do need some guidance on how to create this trigger.  Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Hi there @user1799724! Could you please clarify where you need help in the trigger creation process?

Comment: sorry about being vague - the issue is onEdit triggers the script on desktop and on mobile but onEdit cannot write data to a new spreadsheet so it does not work - how will the script know to run when I click the checkbox.

I see the function createinstallableonedittrigger() - how do I use that - sorry as I am a novice so it might be a very silly question.  Do I need to deploy or something and then will it be able to put data on another spreadsheet

Comment: thanks so much to all of you for your help and time.  It is much appreciated

Comment: @user1799724 The trigger doesn't fire because it hasn't been created yet. To create it you should run the `createinstallableonedittrigger` function once. That function will check if the trigger exists, and if it doesn't it will create it. To run that function, open the project on the [Apps Script IDE](https://script.google.com/), select the function and click on `Run`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments on [Cooper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70551904/11861954) I am writing this answer to expand its clarity in order to help you and the community. First of all I advise you to familiarise yourself with [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Cooper developed an edit installable trigger on the function `createinstallableonedittrigger`. As the docs say, an edit installable trigger:

> An installable edit trigger runs when a user modifies a value in a
> spreadsheet.

The `createinstallableonedittrigger` runs a check before creating the trigger. It is checking if a trigger with that same name (`newfunctionname`) already exists, and if it doesn't it proceeds to create it. To do so the code is [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array of existing triggers pulled by [`getProjectTriggers`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app?hl=en#getprojecttriggers), and if the answer is empty (read as *zero length*) then proceeds to create the trigger. So as I explained in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547491/onedite-script-works-halfway-but-when-i-change-it-to-script-run-when-i-click-i#comment124759689_70551904), you should run the function `createinstallableonedittrigger` once to create the trigger.

The trigger logic is coded onto the `newfunctionname` function. Notice how it uses the `e` ([event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)) parameter to analyse the firing action. Particularly, it uses the `range` property to get a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object. Finally, the script runs your trigger operations. Please let me know if you need further clarifications. For better legibility, I share here one copy of Cooper' script:

```js
function newfunctionname(e) {
  const s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == 'SCAN' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart ==
    5 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.setValue("FALSE"); //set the check box back to false      
    var theRoll = s.getRange("A4").getValue();
    var statusPage = SpreadsheetApp.openById(
      '1CYZO6fP3APscxDLS881x3eJ9YEC9ydBXDxvmPaSUwU0');
    var statusSheet = statusPage.getSheetByName("DailyCut");
    var lr1 = statusSheet.getLastRow();
    var range = statusSheet.getRange(2, 1, lr1 - 1, 4).getValues();
    var barCode = s.getRange("A2").getValue();
    for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
      if (barCode == range[j][1]) {
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 16).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat(
          'h:mm');
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 14).setValue("Robin");
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 15).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat(
          'dd-mm-yyyy');
        statusSheet.getRange(j + 2, 17).setValue(theRoll);
        j = range.length;

      }
    }
    s.getRange(2, 1).setValue("");
    s.getRange(4, 1).setValue("");
    s.getRange(5, 1).setValue(false);
  }
}

function createinstallableonedittrigger() {
  if (ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() ==
      "newfunctionnname").length == 0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('newfunctionname').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp
      .getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this helps - I will try again - I have yet to make it work.